# PL SQL variable type in case of join

Tags: oracle, variables, join, plsql

I would like to know how to declare a PL SQL variable in case when the result is a join of two tables. For e.g.,

```
DECLARE 
 variable_name table_name%ROWTYPE% 
BEGIN
 SELECT * into variable_name from a,b
 where a.x=b.x
END
```

-First assuming that this returns just one record. Next case, when we expect multiple records (probably I can use cursor).

In this case, table_name%ROWTYPE% can be only of a particular (single) table. Please point me to the correct post if its already answered. Thanks.

Comment: First of all I'd check if I really need all these columns here. Almost always business logic requires only several attributes and they should be described explicitly, without any '*'.

Comment: @Sanders Yes. I do need to have a `select *`. This is one of the test case picked up from standard benchmark, modified for sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches you might consider:

If the join is used regularly, you could create a view which encapsulates the join, and then declare your type based on the view:

```
CREATE VIEW myjoin as 
SELECT *  from a,b
    where a.x=b.x

variable_name myjoin%ROWTYPE;
```

Alternatively, work out what columns get returned, and declare the record type by hand, example from the docs

```
TYPE myjointype IS RECORD (
x          a.x%TYPE,
x_1        b.x%TYPE
);

variable_name myjointype;
```

In general though, and particularly in this case with a join, it is better to specify the column names explicitly rather than using a select *, as select * from be fragile, particularly in the event that the underlying table definitions change.

Comment: Second way is dangerous. When applying DDL on several servers it can lead some little differences, say, different order of columns. It's safe if enumerate fields in select..into manually, if's safe if using %rowtype, but it can lead unpredictable errors if fetching * into hand-desribed record.

Comment: I agree with @Sanders the Softwarer, it is almost always better to specify the column names eplicitly rather than using select *. Using select * can be very fragile and cause unexpected bugs if, for example the tables are modified

Comment: And there is a third approach: DECLARE a CURSOR with the select and give the Variable cursor_name%ROWTYPE, then you can even use * and it will fit the table... Or even Shorter: `FOR my_value IN (SELECT * FROM ...) LOOP` and my_value has the fitting type....